# Understanding one-way binding with angular 1.5

Tags: javascript, angularjs, data-binding

There is one thing I don't understand with one-way bindings demonstrated by the code and demo below:

```
var example = {
    bindings: {
        obj: '<',
        prim: '<'
    },
    template: `
        <div class="section">
            <h4>
                Isolate Component
            </h4>
            <p>Object: {{ $ctrl.obj }}</p>
            <p>Primitive: {{ $ctrl.prim }}</p>
            <a href="" ng-click="$ctrl.updateValues();">
                Change Isolate Values
            </a>
        </div>
    `,
    controller: function () {
        this.updateValues = function () {
            this.prim = 10;
            this.obj = {
                john: {
                    age: 35,
                    location: 'Unknown'
                }
            };
        };
    }
};

function ParentController() {
    this.somePrimitive = 99;
    this.someObject = {
        todd: {
            age: 25,
            location: 'England, UK'
        }
    };
    this.updateValues = function () {
        this.somePrimitive = 33;
        this.someObject = {
            jilles: {
                age: 20,
                location: 'Netherlands'
            }
        };
    };
}

angular
   .module('app', [])
   .component('example', example)
   .controller('ParentController', ParentController);
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/sdxuc80o/36/)

The thing I don't understand is how the primitive value changes (or doesn't change) if you modify it in the isolated scope. As far as I understand if you one-way bind a primitive, the binding will break if you change that value within the isolated scope. With `break` I mean that an update by the parent will not propagate anymore into the isolated scope. 
However, in the demo it doesn't exactly work like that.

HOW TO REPRODUCE: Go to the [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/sdxuc80o/36/) and first click the `Change isolate values` button. This will change the primitive in the isolated scope. Next click the `Change Parent Values` button. As you can see the primitive within the isolated scope is still updated. Based on this, I guess the binding doesn't break if you update a primitive inside the isolated scope, right?! But now things get weird. If you repeat this, you'll notice that this time the binding doesn't work anymore.

Can someone explain why the primitive value did change the first time but didn't the second time ?

UPDATE: Found the solution. The binding works perfect, because the value of the parent doesn't change anymore, its always 10. [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/sdxuc80o/37/) is an updated example which shows that it still works

Comment: quoting toddmotto: ["Objects in JavaScript are bound by reference, and Angular doesn’t make a copy of the Object when passing into one-way bindings, it actually sets the same value, which means Objects are somewhat two-way bound still."](https://toddmotto.com/one-way-data-binding-in-angular-1-5/)

Comment: My question is not about the object, but about the primitive